# Minimal change algorithm for permutations

Tags: c#, permutation

My teacher gave me this [algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dOOz.png) of generating permutations and said that it's minimal change algorithm. The problem is I can't implement it correctly - it loops forever. Here's my code:

```
class Program
{
    private static int[] a;
    private static int[] d;
    private static int[] pos;

    public static void Swap(int[] source, int index1, int index2)
    {
        int temp = source[index1];
        source[index1] = source[index2];
        source[index2] = temp;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 3;
        a = new int[n + 2];
        d = new int[n + 2];
        pos = new int[n + 2];

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        {
            a[i] = pos[i] = i;
            d[i] = -1;
        }

        int m = 0;
        a[0] = a[n + 1] = n + 1;

        while (m != 1)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
            {
                Console.Write(a[i] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            m = n;
            while(a[pos[m]+d[m]] > m)
            {
                d[m] = -d[m];
                m = m - 1;
            }

            Swap(a, a[pos[m]], a[pos[m] + d[m]]);
            Swap(pos, pos[m], pos[a[pos[m]] + d[m]]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I was searching for this algorithm and found another [pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZCQm.jpg), it slightly different from first one, but it doesn't work either.
I would like to use Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter algorithm or anything else, and I feel like given algorithm is wrong, but teacher insist that it's correct.

So are there any errors or I can ignore teacher and use what I want to?

Comment: I'm confused on this post, you say your implementation isn't working and you feel it's wrong, on what basis? Maybe your attempt is wrong, can you write your own algorithm or do you have to take the one your teacher gave you and implement it?

Comment: I think it's wrong because of two reasons: 1. There's two versions of pseudocode, and I don't think they both correct simultaneously. 2. I was following given pseudocode and it does not work, I also was following second pseudocode and it does not work too. So, my question are there in my implementation errors compare to pseudocode?   I should use given, but obviously if it's wrong I need to use correct algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one thing I noticed is that swap should receive indexes and you're sending the values of the cells you want to swap:

```
Swap(a, pos[m], pos[m] + d[m]);
Swap(pos, m, a[pos[m]] + d[m]);
```